# Get inserted ID back from SqlConnection.Execute stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, dapper, sqlconnection

I'm inserting data into my database like so:

```
using (IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Execute(storedProcedure, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

I've added `select SCOPE_IDENTITY();` to my stored procedures so now the id is returned from the query. How can I access it?

Comment: If you're only inserting a single row, personally I would assign the value of `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to an output parameter, rather than selecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like Dapper, yes? So: instead of using `Execute`, use `QuerySingle<T>` for whatever `T` you are selecting - presumably `int` or `long`:

```cs
var id = conn.QuerySingle<int>(storedProcedure, parameters,
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

As a side note: you may find it easier to [use the `OUTPUT` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) during the `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

Use ExecuteScalar.

```
using (IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   var command = conn.CreateCommand();
   command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   command.CommandText = "MyProcedure";
   var id = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
}
```